# Workflow Can Only be Started by Some Users SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I modify the old workflow and publish it, but when I start it, it's showing an error. Is any permission to set this workflow? When I create new workflow, that time new workflow is started correctly.

Comment: Does your workflow do something that would require specific permissions. For example, does it create an item in another list where the users don't have contribute permissions?

Comment: Yes. so how can i set permission?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before, as well. Ensure that the individuals accessing the site have at least read permissions at the site collection and to the list they are accessing. Then you can disinherit from there. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To create an item in another list, when the user doesn't have contribute permissions, you must use an impersonation step in your workflow. Then the new item in the other list will be created with the permissions of the person who published the workflow.

Comment: Can i set set higher permission instead use impersonation step in workflow?

Comment: Yes. If you want to give all of those users contribute permissions to the other list, that would work.